# Duplicate answer output when calling method on line.isEmpty()

Tags: java, while-loop, duplicates, java.util.scanner

I've written a program that takes input(either user typed or processed via a text file) and calls mathematical calculations based on what it finds.

The problem is once it comes to an answer and prints it out, for every `line.isEmpty()` the scanner detects it will recalculate and print out the previous answer. If there is 4 blank lines, it will be printed 4 times until another problem is parsed into the program.

Here is my main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calc calc = new Calc();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String input = "";
    List<String> strs = new ArrayList<>();
    //
    ArrayList<String> tokens;
    //this makes sure an entire problem is added as a tokens element
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = sc.nextLine().trim();
        if (line.isEmpty()) {
            for (String s : strs) {
                sb.append(s);
                input = sb.toString();
            }
            tokens = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(input.split(" ")));
            //call calculate on strs then reset
            calc.calculate(tokens);
            strs.clear();
            tokens.clear();
            sb.setLength(0);
        } else if (line.length() == 1) {
            strs.add(" ");
            strs.add(line);
            strs.add(" ");
        } else {
            strs.add(line);
        }
    }
}
```

and the calculate method:

```
public String calculate(List<String> tokens) {
    operands = new Stack<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.size(); i++) {
        tokens.removeAll(Arrays.asList(""));
    }
    String result = processOperands(tokens);

    if (result.equals(null)) {
        System.out.println(result);
        return defaultResult;
    } else if (result.equals("java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempting to add with fewer than 2 operands.")) {
        System.out.println(result);
        return "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Attempting to add with fewer than 2 operands.";
    } else {
        System.out.println(result);
        return result.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");
    }
}
```

For input of :

```
2 2 +


4 
3 +
```

Output:

```
4
4
4
7
```

Obviously the issue is I am calling calculate every time it detects an empty string, since that is currently how it knows when a problem is finished being 'input'.

How could I modify this to either know to not print the same answer twice, or to not calculate the answer until another one is found?

Comment: That's already in the code. `calc.calculate(tokens);
            strs.clear();
            tokens.clear();
            sb.setLength(0);`

Comment: What have you done so far to figure out why the problem occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input variable is not being reset in your logic.  After you clear strs, tokens, and reset the 'sb' variable, set input = "";

Comment: My logic was wrong and was trying to do `line = "";` instead. Thanks!